# Efficient ways to remove select words from a PHP Array

Tags: php, arrays, keyword

I created an array to fetch a file and then parse the contents of that file.  I already filtered out the words less than 4 characters with `if(strlen($value) < 4): unset($content[$key]); endif;`

My question is this - I want to remove common words from the array, but there is quite a few of them.  Instead of doing these checks over and over and over on each array value, I was wondering if there was a more efficient way to do this?

Here's a sample of the code I currently am using.  This list could be huge and I am thinking that there has to be a better(more efficient) way?

```
foreach ($content as $key=>$value) {
    if(strlen($value) < 4): unset($content[$key]); endif; 
    if($value == 'that'): unset($content[$key]); endif;
    if($value == 'have'): unset($content[$key]); endif;
    if($value == 'with'): unset($content[$key]); endif;
    if($value == 'this'): unset($content[$key]); endif;
    if($value == 'your'): unset($content[$key]); endif;
    if($value == 'will'): unset($content[$key]); endif;
    if($value == 'they'): unset($content[$key]); endif;
    if($value == 'from'): unset($content[$key]); endif;
    if($value == 'when'): unset($content[$key]); endif;
    if($value == 'then'): unset($content[$key]); endif;
    if($value == 'than'): unset($content[$key]); endif;
    if($value == 'into'): unset($content[$key]); endif;
}
```

Comment: At a minimum, I recommend using `elseif` for each check after the first.  If `$value == 'that'`, there's no need to continue checking for the other possible values.  There are better ways to approach the problem, as indicated in the answers; I just wanted to point out something that you might be able to apply to other code that you have written.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how I'd do it:

```
$exlcuded_words = array( 'that','have','with','this','your','will','they','from','when','then','than','into');
$replace = array_fill_keys($exlcuded_words,'');
echo str_replace(array_keys($replace),$replace,'some words that have to be with this your will they have from when then that into replaced');
```

The way it works: make an array, full of empty strings, where the keys are the substrings you want to remove/replace. the just use `str_replace`, pass the keys as a first argument, the array itself as the second argument and, in the result in this case is: `some words to be replaced`. This code has been tested and works just fine.

When dealing with an array, just implode it with some wacky delimiter (like `%@%@%` or something) and `str_replace` the lot, explode the lot again and *Bob's your uncle*

---

When it comes to replacing all words with less than 3 characters (which I forgot about in my original answer), that's something a regex is good at... I'd say something like `preg_replace('(\b|[^a-z])[a-z]{1,3}(\b|[^a-z])/i','$1$2',implode(',',$targetArray));` or someting like that. 
You might want to test this one out, because this is just off the top of my head, and untested. But this would seem to enough to get you started

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this will be better:

```
$filter = array("that","have","with",...);

foreach ($content as $key=>$value) {
   if (in_array($value,$filter)){
      unset($content[$key])
   }
}
```

Comment: instead of `in_array`, IMO it's better to use `array_key_exists` or `isset($filter[$content])`. It's faster then `in_array` and the result is pretty much the same

Answer (score 1):

I would probably do something like this:

```
$aCommonWords = array('that','have','with','this','yours','etc.....');

foreach($content as $key => $value){
    if(in_array($value,$aCommonWords)){
        unset($content[$key]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Make an array of words you want to remove and check if the value is inside that array

```
$exlcuded_words = array( 'that','have','with','this','your','will','they','from','when','then','than','into');
```

and if `foreach`

```
if (in_array($value, $excluded_words)) unset($content[$key];
```

Comment: I would reconsider removing all less than 3 letter words. What with abbreviations or contractions

Answer (score 0):

Another possible solution:

```php
$arr = array_flip(array( 'that', 'have', 'with', 'this', 'your', 'will', 
        'they', 'from', 'when', 'then', 'than', 'into' ));
foreach ($content as $key=>$value) {
    if(strlen($value) < 4 || isset($arr[$value])) {
        unset($content[$key]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`array_diff()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php):

```
$content = array('here','are','some','words','that','will','be','filtered');
$filter = array('that','have','here','are','will','they','from','when','then');
$result = array_diff($content, $filter);
```

**RESULT:**

```
Array
(
    [2] => some
    [3] => words
    [6] => be
    [7] => filtered
)
```

Alternately, if you want more flexibility in terms of what gets filtered (e.g., you mentioned needing to filter out words less than 4 characters), you can use [`array_filter()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php):

```
$result = array_filter($content, function($v) use ($filter) {
    return !in_array($v, $filter) && strlen($v) >= 4;
});
```

**RESULT:**

```
Array
(
    [2] => some
    [3] => words
    [7] => filtered
)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$var = array('abb', 'bffb', 'cbbb', 'dddd', 'dddd', 'f', 'g');
$var= array_unique($var);
foreach($var as $val){
    echo $val. " ";
}
```

Result :

```
abb
bffb
cbbb
dddd
f
g
```

The easiest way

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!